# How do I get all the variable names (inside handlebars) within a html string?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, variables, handlebars.js

If I had the string:

```
const html = 
`<div>
    <button>Increase Count</button>     
    <div>{{ 'Double count:' + count * 2 }}</div>     
    <div>{{ age }}</div>   
</div>`
```

With handlebarJs I can evaluate the string with

```
const template = Handlebars.compile(html);
template({ count:4, age:10, name:'John' });
```

Which would return

```
`<div>
    <button>Increase Count</button>     
    <div>Double count: 8</div>     
    <div>10}</div>   
</div>`
```

Is there a way (within or without) using handlebarJs to return all the variables used to evaluate the string.

In this case we should get: `[count, age]` and not `name` because is is not used.

I was thinking of using regex, but it would be hard to isolate just the variables within the js.

```
const regex = /{{([^}]*)}}/g;

const htmlString = '<html><body>Hello, {{name}}!</body></html>';

let variables = [];
let match;
while (match = regex.exec(htmlString)) {
  variables.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(variables); // Output: ["name"]
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, I got all the text inside the double curly brackets, then used acorn and acorn-walk to parse the JS and find identifiers.